# Listeners are not working for textfield

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

I am using ExtJS 6 and in Project I have am using `textfield` but my listners are not working. am I doing anything wrong. Can anybody please help me.

My code example.

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    title: 'Contact Info',
    width: 300,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'name',
        fieldLabel: 'Name',
        allowBlank: false,  
        listeners: {
            keypress : function() {
                alert("Name")
            }
        }    
    }, {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'email',
        fieldLabel: 'Email Address',
        vtype: 'email',  
        listeners: {
            keypress : function() {
                alert("Email")
            }
        }    
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For performance reasons, `keypress`, `keydown`, `keyup` events are disabled by default, and have to be enabled using [`enableKeyEvents:true`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/Ext.form.field.Text.html#cfg-enableKeyEvents).

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with your listeners. What you missing is `enableKeyEvents`. Whenever you are using key events you need to set `enableKeyEvents : true`. You can check in [Doc](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/classic/Ext.form.field.Text.html)

I created a fiddle for you you can check this is working fine here. [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1jfk)